# How can I rewrite my image path?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

In inspect element image path is showing like 
`../wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Hydrangeas.jpg`

while I want it to show like `../images/Hydrangeas.jpg` by url rewrite.
Is it possible with `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your .htacces file which will achieve what you want.

Redirect 301 /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Hydrangeas.jpg www.example.com/images/Hydrangeas.jpg

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to place this snippet in your wp-config.php file:

`define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'images' );`

there's no need in touching .htaccess

Comment: I don't want to show actual path to user. this will upload all images to this folder. Images are already uploaded. If I am fetching them actual path should not displayed

Comment: @AmolKanherkar check out this article then http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?228498-RESOLVED-Hide-Image-Source-using-PHP-and-Sessions